# Autolaunch exe on USB in windows XP SP3

Tags: windows, usb, autorun, windows-xp-sp3, autoplay

I want to autolaunch my application on USB as soon as I plug it into a PC running on windows XP SP3. I have made an autorun.inf (having below written code) and also tried to lauch setup using a batch file(autorun.bat) but none of these seem to be working.

I have also read that a particular windows update (KB971029) disables the autorun/autoplay feature of USB. How can I overcome it? (I can't ask my client to uninstall a windows security update for using my product..)

### Code Of autorun.inf file

```
[autorun]
UseAutoPlay=1
icon=setup.exe
Open=setup.exe
action="Start my application"
Label=setup


[Autoplay]
shellexecute=autorun.bat
Icon=setup.exe
```

My product contains some media (video) files too so on inserting the USB I get a pop up asking following options
1.) to open files in explorer 
2.) play files using media player
3.) take no action

Comment: try setting "use autoplay=0" when it =1 it will prompt the user what they want to do setting this to 0 will basically turn off auto play. hope this helps. also look up auto run at microsoft.com.

Answer (score 2):

If autorun is disabled, you cannot use autorun.  It's that simple.

Comment: I checked in my group policy setings turn off autoplay is set to "not configured" (read my edit too)